# insert random number in mysql database depend on certain column in php

Tags: php, mysql

I've been searching for few hours and I have no idea how to do this. I have a table books which its column AccesstionNo would be inserted as unique random number. But it also depend on another column "Description" if the description is CD the accesstionno most be like "CD-random Number".
how can i do this thing in php and mysql??

I've tried this, I know it have problems but that what i think about.. where $accesstion is a value i defined to be inserted in the table.

### and PhysicalDesc is column from database

```
$accesstion=0; 
if(PhysicalDesc=="CD") { 
  $accesstion= "CD-"rand(100000,999999); 
} else { 
 $accesstion=rand(100000,999999); 
}
```

Comment: You need to upgrade or insert new row?

Comment: 'unique random number' - no such thing consider using uuid https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid and consider having 2 fields with a composite key

Comment: i want to insert not to upgrade.

Comment: Use AUTO_INCREMENT in database each time you enter data it will give a random unique id. see here : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

Comment: @Dilek auto_increment numbers are in no way random.

Comment: Please show us some code of what you have tried so far so we can better assist.

Comment: @P.Salmon thanks for correcting! no value has to be specified for the AUTO_INCREMENT column, MySQL assignes sequence numbers automatically  :) :)  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html I know what its. For the OP! difference between random and AUTO_INCREMENT is, random means randomly created numbers and AUTO_INCREMENT means increases the numbers by +1 boths are unique and matchless

Comment: @loletamhamad You need to set your id as char or varchar or other types to insert id manuel, You cant insert values into a auto_increment column. But you can UPDATE id column like this `update your table set id=1 where id=100` so id 100 will be changed to 1. and **why do you want to change id**?

Comment: have you tried `uniqid` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php or `random_int` https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php, read on both before deciding what to use, one more can help Unix time stamp.

Answer (score 0):

update you'r unique Id to

so on each insert it will increment the previous Id by one

```
AUTO_INCREMENT
```

ex1 :to Add AUTO_INCREMENT to you'r table on create table

```
   CREATE TABLE table_name
 ( 
  column1 datatype NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 column2 datatype [ NULL | NOT NULL ],
  ...
  );
```

ex2 :to Add AUTO_INCREMENT to you'r table on  (UPDATE Column)

```
  ALTER TABLE table_name AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Comment: but what about CD description??